# jQuery-UI <button> automatically submits its form

Tags: jquery, html

When I click a `<button>`, automatically a (GET-)submit event is triggered. How can I turn this behaviour off?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Button has a [default of type submit](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5). Simply add `type="button"` to the markup

Comment: Not just "some browsers," it's in the specs: [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON), [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I seem to remember some ie quirk where you had to state type="submit" -> see http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/button-wont-submit-in-ie

Comment: @reqsquare: I haven't done a comprehensive survey, wouldn't be entirely surprised if something, somewhere got it wrong. (**Edit** re your comment edit: Ah, yes, that *was* the culprit I suspected.) But it *is* the specified behavior that the default value of `type` is "submit" for `button` elements.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Yup, that is why I said most to begin with - I remembered a bug once way back!